# Auto Sizing Labels in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qlabel

I'm developing a Qt application and it's currently in an internal beta test. One member of the company has Windows configured to display text larger than its normal size, which breaks my UI. The About page, for example, currently looks like this:

[image: Normal appearance]

but under his settings, looks like this (note the clipped text):

[image: Large text appearance]

Coming from a C#/Winforms background, I'm amazed that I can't seem to find some easily configurable label property such as [Form.AutoSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.autosize.aspx) that will automatically size the labels to fit their containing text. I've tried messing with `sizePolicy`, `scaledContents`, and a few other properties, but none seem to do this.

I've come across various threads (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202717/for-qt-4-6-x-how-to-auto-size-text-to-fit-in-a-specified-width)) which give instructions for scaling the text to the label, but I want to do the opposite - scale the *label* to the *text* to facilitate for those with enlarged text settings like my co-worker. Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Comment: You should use layouts: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/layout.html

Comment: QLabel must support this by default (if put into layout of course). Do you use layout for this form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least three solutions to this problem.

1. Use layouts. Their contents are scaled according to the size of the window.
2. Make a code which is executed whenever window size is changed. In that code, you get the width of the longest text in the window ([How?](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Archived:Calculating_text_width_in_Qt))([another way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633433/qt-get-the-pixel-length-of-a-string-in-a-qlabel)) and then set window wider than that.
3. Do the same as in solution #2, but execute the code only when the dialog is shown. After that, alter the window properties so that its size cannot be changed.